# First execute event receiver and afterwards run JavaScript to redirect URL?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-addin

Is there a way on edit form , to first execute the item updating event receiver and afterwards execute the PreSaveAction function to redirect to another URL?

It seems that JavaScript function executes first. I want to execute first the event receiver.

Thanks!

Comment: There might be, but it depends on what SharePoint version you're using.

Comment: I'm using SharePoint Online